# how to insert contact to a group?

Tags: android, contacts

I want to add a `contact` to a specific group I am having all the group names and their Id's by using `ContactsContract.Groups._ID`, now I want to add a `contact` to a group by this `id`. i.e insert some `contact id` to some `group id`.

I have retrieved both group and Raw contact id's please tell me the query to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer at [How do I add contact to a group on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491546/how-do-i-add-contact-to-a-group-on-android.Thanks) to Pentium10

```
public Uri addToGroup(long personId, long groupId) {

        //remove if exists
    //    this.removeFromGroup(personId, groupId);

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.RAW_CONTACT_ID,
                personId);
        values.put(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.GROUP_ROW_ID,
                groupId);
        values
                .put(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.MIMETYPE,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);

        return this.ctx.getContentResolver().insert(
                ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, values);

    }
```

Comment: you could simply point to the answer in comments instead of posting that as you own answer.