# Sync Contacts with Android Application

Tags: android, synchronization, contacts, accountmanager

I want to add my application in sync option in Android -> Setting.

I have created Sync Adapter and it works perfect..

But my contacts are not added under my account..
I got my account under "Contact to display" but when i select my account, there is no contacts in that account.
Can anyone please help me out...

I have referred a lot like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3336019/new-contacts-created-using-contactscontract-do-not-appear-in-contacts-app) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491546/how-do-i-add-contact-to-a-group-on-android).

But my issue is not discussed in any of them..
Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this link to handle your apps idle time

[Application idle time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075180/application-idle-time)

and in (taken from that answer)

```
public class ControlApplication extends Application{

    private static final String TAG=ControlApplication.class.getName();
    private Waiter waiter;  //Thread which controls idle time

    // only lazy initializations here!
    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d(TAG, "Starting application"+this.toString());
        waiter=new Waiter(15*60*1000); //15 mins
        waiter.start();
        setContentView(R.layout.blackscreen);
    }

    public void touch(){
        waiter.touch();
    }
}
```

you can call an xml file which has background as black using

**EDIT**

blackscreen.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
```

Comment: But where to write this code??

Comment: Can u give me full file code??

Comment: ok.. i vl test n let u knw.. sorry bt m a beginner in android so i got confuse with lots of things...

Comment: Okie.. leave a comment when u r done ..

Comment: working ? Then why is the other  answer marked correct ?

Comment: i tested that n it worked... i vl implement ur solution also...

Comment: @angel..Please put in some effort and find how to do it. I dnt think it such a hectic task .

Comment: I did it bt m getting error at stop method. it says u cannot override final method...
So i m not getting any userful output as i have commented stop method.. :(

Comment: any idea how to overcome this problem?? @BenilMathew

Comment: @angel .. Start your Activity in this method.. 
    public void onUserInteraction()
    {
        super.onUserInteraction();
        getApp().touch();setContentView(R.layout.MainActivity);
        Log.d(TAG, "User interaction to "+this.toString());
    }